How can government immunity for violating constitution be constitutional?
If a law nominally exists, but is supplemented with immunity for violating it, does the law effectively exists? "Thou shalt not kill, but if you kill, that's OK, no repercussions whatsoever."
I am puzzled how the qualified immunity for violating civil rights enumerated in the amendments (e.g. the 1st, 4th, 5th) can possibly be constitutional, for it negates the civil rights. Could you elucidate the logic of it?

Qualified immunity relieves people who are accused of violating the civil rights of another under 42 U.S.C. § 1983 (and in Bivens actions which were federal common law claims against federal employees for violating the civil rights of another) of liability, when the constitutional right that is violated isn't "clearly established."
The concept behind qualified immunity is that law enforcement officers aren't lawyers and shouldn't be held accountable for money damages because they fail to predict how the constitution will be interpreted in a novel situation.
It is closely related to the court established case law interpretation of 42 U.S.C. § 1983 which requires a claim for money damages for a civil rights violation to be based upon intentional conduct of the defendant. How can conduct be an intentional deprivation of someone's civil rights if the fact that the conduct violates someone's civil rights isn't clearly established?
The way that "clearly established" has been interpreted by the courts, however, is often crabbed and often protects clearly improper activities that simply haven't been presented to a court in the fact-pattern presented.
Incidentally, § 1983 liability and Bivens liability is primarily liability for individuals. There is no vicarious or respondeat superior liability for this liability (although indemnification agreements with police unions often make this effectively the case). Local governments (but not state governments or the federal government) can have liability under § 1983 for themselves taking acts that lead to civil rights violations as a matter of policy. All governments are subject to injunctive relief when their policies violate the constitution, but that isn't money damages for someone who has been harmed by a past violation.

It's too bad courts aren't willing to recognize that immunity should only apply for actions which are undertaken in a good faith effort to obey the Constitution, and not merely an effort to keep infringements just below the level a court would find actionable.

If the courts refuse to consider a claim because the violation hasn't been clearly established yet, and the courts are the ones supposed to clearly establish, how on Earth can anything become established? Can an officer abuse a citizen to death in a novel creative manner never tried before and escape accountability because the courts have never faced that particular manner of abuse? And, because the courts would never consider it due to its novelty can other officers nationwide do the same without any repercussions?

@Michael: Until fairly recently, the courts would first decide whether the right was violated (thus clearly establishing it for future cases), and then decide whether the right had already been clearly established beforehand. But then the Supreme Court ruled that lower courts (and SCOTUS itself) could conduct this inquiry in the opposite order, and stop at the "not clearly established" step rather than going on to evaluate the novel context.

@Michael This is indeed a problem with qualified immunity.

@Kevin: Indeed, as one judge observed (I forget who), this leads to a situation where the more patently unlawful someone's action is, the greater the likelihood that there won't be any precedent characterizing it is unlawful because nobody in the past had been brazen enough to claim that it wasn't.

I will not defend qualified immunity. You are not alone in your criticism of it:

Cato Institute
Institute for Justice
Supreme Court Justice Clarence Thomas

But it does not operate how you describe it.
Qualified immunity relates to personal liability. It does not excuse the constitutional wrong generally. A fourth amendment violation can still result in the evidence being inadmissible. A first amendment violation may still be remedied by striking down the flawed law, or by issuing an injunction against the bad state actor(s). Etc.
Qualified immunity simply restricts the possibility of recovering money damages from the individual state actors in their personal capacity, typically sought via a § 1983 claim or a Bivens claim.

Largely correct, but not really correct in the Fourth Amendment space, where there's a "good faith" exception to the exclusionary rule, allowing evidence that was obtained illegally but in a way that courts don't find bad enough to punish.

@bdb484: It's a shame courts aren't willing to acknowledge that many Fourth-Amendment cases involve disputed matters of fact, and defendants should be allowed to have juries instructed that they should only apply certain evidence against the defendant if they believe certain parts of a cop's testimony.  If a jury thinks a cop invented his justification for a search after the fact, that shjould be a basis for them disregarding any evidence found therein.  Having them not see the evidence may be better than merely instructing them to disregard it, but having them told they should apply...

...the evidence only if they believe the cop would still be far less bad than telling them they must accept as incontrovertible the legitimacy of the search,
